# batch command to store a folder name in a file in single line

Tags: batch

I have a list of folders in a directory, i need to copy just all the folder name to a file and the file should be in a single line seperated by delims. can any help me with this in a batch file.

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @SivaCharan it's not so simple, as echo produces a new line.

Comment: The echo command built into cmd.exe doesn't support it, but the echos built into the Unix shells add a `-n` option that suppresses the trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

In batch you'd do it like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /D %%f in (*.*) do set n=!n!;%%f

if defined n echo %n:~1% > list.txt

endlocal
```

To recurse into subfolders replace `/D` with `/R` and `*.*` with `.`.

```
for /R %%f in (.) do set n=!n!;%%f
```

By adding qualifiers to the loop variable you can specify if you want just the name of the folder (`%%~nxf`) or the full path (`%%~dpnxf`).

Comment: This gets just the files, no subdirectories.  That could be what the OP meant, but I interpreted his question (perhaps mistakenly) as asking for the opposite, subdirs only, no files.  But I still gave you an upvote for doing it with cmd.exe.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot the `/D` for directory enumeration. It's fixed now in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is not single batch file command that does what you want, but you could use a batch file to accomplish the task and `call` it from your own. Ansgar Wiechers' answer had the right basic idea (I see he's fixed his version after I posted mine).

Anyway, here's a version that will produce a semicolon delimited list of first level subfolders in either the current directory or one passed to it as an argument. I chose to use a semicolon delimiter rather than, say, a comma, because it could never be part a valid filename (and commas can be, although it's uncommon).

If a given folder name has spaces in it, it must be quoted it like this (otherwise quoting the folder's directory path is optional):

```
subdirs "C:\Documents and Settings"
```

Note it only prints the list to the console (stdout), so if you want to save that in a file, you'll need append a `> filename.ext` after the script file name (and any folder name) to redirect the output into file of your choice:

```
subdirs C:\Windows > dirlist.txt
```

== subdirs.bat ==

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd %1
for /D %%d in (*.*) do set n=!n!;%%d
if defined n echo %n:~1%
popd
endlocal
```

If you'd like to produce the full path to each folder name, you can change the `set n=!n!;%%d` to `set n=!n!;%%~fd` in the `for` loop line.

Comment: Might be easier to `cd` into the root directory than to prepend the pattern with a path: `if "%1" neq "" cd "%1"`

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: You're right, but it'll need to save and restore the current directory so that's not a permanent side-effect. I'll incorporate that along with another simplification I have planned. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: +1 for `pushd`. Haven't used this in ages.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: Thanks again. I've simplified my answer even more after realizing checking whether a folder path argument was supplied or not wasn't really necessary. I also changed the delimiter to a semicolon to avoid confusion with possible subfolder names.